# How to ignore perm errors with Path::Tiny 'visit'? (Windows)

Tags: windows, perl

Is there a way to use Path::Tiny to recursively visit directories and files while not aborting completely if an item is inaccessible for some reason?

Specifically, on Windows using Strawberry perl 5.32.1.

AFAICT Path::Tiny's `visit` mechanism unconditionally throws an exception if opendir fails, as it is likely to do on various Window-ish system things.

```
use strict; use warnings;
use Path::Tiny qw/path/;
path(".")->visit(
  sub{ print "Visiting $_[0]\n"; }, { recurse => 1 });

print "Done (did not abort)\n";
```

Running this on Windows (in an Aministrator command window) in the root of C: gives:

```
Visiting $Recycle.Bin
Visiting $WinREAgent
Visiting BOOTNXT
Visiting bootTel.dat
Visiting Brother
Visiting Jts
...
Error opendir on 'Documents and Settings': Invalid argument at Y:\test.pl line 3.
```

... and the contents of the folders Brother, Jts, etc. are never visited at all.

Comment: Wrap it in a [Try::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/Try::Tiny)'s `try`?

Comment: Correct, unconditional. At best, you could monkey patch `_throw`

Comment: Try [Path::Tiny::Rule](https://metacpan.org/pod/Path::Iterator::Rule). It has better error handling.

Comment: Failing alternatives, what ikegami said... You could try defining your own Path::Tiny::NoOpendirErr (or something like that) subclass overriding just the method that aborts (apparently _throw). It looks like the first argument to the _throw method is the function that failed, in this case 'opendir', so it should mostly boil down to checking the first argument and either returning or calling parent's _throw()